# Adding user to the group owning a folder doesn't give that user access

Tags: permissions, users, group

I have the following folders:

```
drwx------  4 ccote    domain^users            4096 Apr 17 11:18 ccote
drwxrwx---  2 ccote    ccote_jponchar_gnicolas 4096 Feb 20 10:58 ccote-jponchar-gnicolas
drwx------ 14 gnicolas domain^users            4096 Nov 28  2014 gnicolas
drwx------  3 jgodbout domain^users            4096 Oct 24  2014 jgodbout
drwx------  2 jponchar domain^users            4096 Sep 22  2014 jponchar
drwxr-xr-x  2 pagagne  domain^users            4096 Jun  2 15:28 pagagne
drwx------  4 plavigne domain^users            4096 Feb 26 14:57 plavigne
```

I want to give the `pagagne` **user** access to the `ccote-jponchar-gnicolas` **folder**. I use the following command to add that user to the `ccote_jponchar_gnicolas` **group** for that folder:

```
usermod -a -G ccote_jponchar_gnicolas pagagne
```

However, that user receives the following message when trying to access the folder:

```
bash: cd: ccote-jponchar-gnicolas/: Permission denied
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user `pagagne` will need to logout and login to his/her shell for the group to be visible in his groups.

You could also check if the user has indeed been added to the group:

```
groups pagagne
```

Comment: Ooops, logout/login...Thanks shivams!

Comment: @SébastienClément if this works for you please remember to tick it so show you've accepted it as your preferred answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try loginning in as a root and running the following command:

```
# usermod pagagne:pagagne ccote-jponchar-gnicolas
```